# How precise can ML classifiers be?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Before tagging thousands of comments and evaluating several ML classifiers I'm curious whether ML classifiers should even be used on the problem below. I've searched the web and stack overflow and only received definitions for precision, recall, accuracy, etc. which is not what I'm looking for.

I need to retrieve customer comments that belong to particular categories so that we know where to make improvements. For example, we need to see the comments regarding "damaged products". The problem is that customers, as you would expect, enter positive comments and negative comments that are very similar.

Lets say we have a series of comments like the following (abbreviated for example)

Negative examples:

- received a product with damage
- very badly damaged product
- much damage to this item

Very similar positive examples:

- received a product with no damage
- very good product no damage
- no damage to this item

Can ML classifiers be trained to identify samples with a high degree of certainty even when the text to be classified is very similar?

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to do using NLP. You should explore NLP concepts in detail, you may find a way to deal with above problem.

Comment: Yes it is called "sentiment analysis" by the way.

Comment: Akshay, I have been using NLP (NLTK, sklearn, etc).I also ran several examples that work well on "demo" data but do poorly on other data. Clement, how would sentiment analysis help with the comments above? On a popular online sentiment analysis tool both sets of comments are negative. Overall, I reworded my final question above to be... well... more precise :)